# How do I define a type for a variable which gets filled by an 'impl' return type of a function?

Tags: function, rust, types, typing

I refer to the example given in 'rustc --explain E0562'. I want an assignment to a variable explicitly typed. How can I do that?

```rust
 { // rustc --explain E0562

  fn count_to_n(n: usize) -> impl Iterator<Item=usize> {
    0..n
  }
  
  let _i = count_to_n( 10); // works

  let _i : &dyn Iterator<Item=usize> = &count_to_n( 10); // works, but is not what I want

  let _i : ... = count_to_n( 10); // how do I get this running?

 }
```

Comment: _Why_ do you want that?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, the whole point of an `impl Trait` return type, is that the implementation and concrete type are an implementation detail that can be changed without breaking other code.